# Voronoi Tessellation - Specifying area size of cells in ratio

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, computational-geometry, voronoi

Is there a way to know where to put points (sites) on a plane and compute the Voronoi diagram consisting of specified area sizes of cells in ratio?

- I'm going to place 3 sites on a plane and I'd like to know *where*
- Constraint: I want areas of each cells to be `52% : 27% : 21%` respectively

The expected result would be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Plane is unbounded. How to calculate ratios of infinite areas? Probably you have bounded areq, like rectangle in image. If given area is rectangle than you can position points on some horizontal or vertical line with distances easily calculated.

Comment: And sum of percentages in example image is 110%?

Comment: @Ante Seriously I sometimes do that. There's no comment but thank you. > 110%

Comment: @Ante "given area is rectangle", that is what I'd like to achieve and you’re absolutely right. And, if possible, I want to point sites **randomly**, so that the result would look more visually dynamic. Perhaps the problem should be, “how to redistribute randomly positioned sites to have given area sizes in ratio”.